# Steam installed, but won't run

Tags: steam

I've read through the answers to similar questions here, but I still haven't figured this out. I installed Steam via the AppCenter, and it seemed to go okay - I managed to get to the login screen and get my account connected, but then ... nothing. When I launch via app, the icon appears in the dock for maybe 10 seconds then disappears. When I launch via Terminal, I get this:

```
Running Steam on elementary 5.1 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
/home/gareth/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
```

... and then nothing. I'm a Linux noob, but very capable and driven to fix problems, so would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What's your GPU? I had a similar problem because I wasn't using the proprietary nvidia driver

Comment: Hello. Can you try installing your graphics drivers from Appcenter, or with the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` ? I think your steam installation was alright, must be a misconfiguration with the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what could cause this, but as a workaround you can try another installing method for Steam, which there are several of.

- There are two different Steam applications listed on the AppCentre.
  From what I've gathered the one called *Steam* is the regular
  installer while the one called *Steam installer* has some slight
  modifications for Ubuntu (which elementary OS is based on). I have used the latter one.
- Valve-provided
  Steam DEB installer. You can find it [here](https://store.steampowered.com/about/) and use [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy.desktop) to
  install it.
- Flatpak at
  https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.valvesoftware.Steam

You can also search and ask for help in Valve's Steam for Linux Client GitHub page:
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues

Comment: Thanks for the help - I tried all 4 methods you gave me, but still not working. I'll go check out the GitHub page now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

type -> steam on your terminal

if your problem is like this ->

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/jacob/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

then you can simply try this command ->

mkdir /home/jacob/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime